# How to bulk load software into nodemcu dev kit?

Tags: lua, bulk, uploading, firmware, nodemcu

For development purposes I have been using the "NodeMCU Firmware Programmer" to flash the firmware to the ESP-12 NodeMCU Dev Kit V2, and then using ESPlorer to upload the lua files.

This works well for development purposes, but now we are moving into commercial production.

Is there a faster way (one-step?) to upload both the NodeMCU firmware and lua files?  I need to program between 1-5k units per month.

Comment: "I need to program between 1-5k units per month" - oh cool, looks like you've come a long way since your first NodeMCU questions in April :)

Comment: My first embedded project.  Really love ESP8266 and NodeMCU - took a while to get used to no-o/s development, but NodeMCU is great and the support from the community is fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a one-step way.

You first [build a file system image using `spiffsimg`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/spiffs/) and then flash both the firmware and the image to the device (with `esptool.py` I suggest).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much, I'll look into spiffsimg!